# React Native props update issue

Tags: react-native

I put the `props` I caught with `redux` in `componentWillMount` to a variable and updated the state.

This is the Image 1:

[image]

I update the `textInput` on the page as shown in the image. But only when it should update the contact array in state. The `company.contract` in Props is also being updated.

This is the Image 2:

[image]

How to prevent Props from updating?

Here are the screen and log message:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: React component state is immutable. Please refer to this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/

Comment: you should refrain from setting state in componentWillMount.
instead set state in componentDidMount that would be better practice.

Comment: I know. But my problem does not change even though I type componentDidMount.